# How to remove the Navigation Controller in story board

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

i added the Navigation controller by Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller to the storyboard and works it well,i added some segue's to it now i want to remove it while i remove it the segue's are deleted now i want reconnect the segue's to the view controller it taking to many steps,there is any other way to Remove the navigation controller without reconnect segue's,Adding the Navigation controller is easy but removing is taking too more steps, is there is any other way to Remove the Navigation controller in story board help me

Comment: why don't you just delete it,just like you delete a normal file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Navigation Controller and delete connection.
2. Make root view to your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it simple. You need to remove navigation controller as you do with each file(select + remove) and reassign the segue you need.